# How to use MongoDB $slice in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am using [monk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monk) in my Node.js app to communicate with MongoDB.
is there a way to use the [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier with the monk driver.

The query I want to run is

```
db.messages.find(
   {"_id" : ObjectId("557c46191e7aef1b02d5db73")},
   { msgs: { $slice: -2 }  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Monk**](https://github.com/Automattic/monk) does not support "projection" or additional argument objects in it's method signature to `.find()`. In order to use the "truly native" features there is a `.col` accessor which allows you to use the native driver collection object:

```js
var db = require('monk')('localhost/test');
var messages = db.get('messages');


messages.col.find({}, { "msgs": { "$slice": -2 } }).toArray(
  function(err,docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log( JSON.stringify( docs, undefined, 2 ) );
  }
);
```

Also note that since this is the native driver you need to call such things as `.toArray()` or other method to deal with the `Cursor` object that is returned. The `.toArray()` element is analogous to what `Monk` operations do by default.

Comment: May `.col` be used on `db` also?